# How to use data in a struct?

Tags: matlab

I need to import data into the variables u and v, and I need 26 versions each of u and v. I tried importing them using eval as u_(1-26):

```
eval(['u_' num2str(k) '=u']);
```

and the same for v, but couldn't figure out how to reference each one later without having to type out the contents of my for loop 26 times. I also tried saying data = load(files) but then I got a "struct" that seemed to have only one instance each of u and v.

Can anyone offer advice on either approach? Sorry if I've left out any important information - I'm not all that familiar with Matlab programming so I'm not sure how much information might be required to answer my question.

Comment: Are you trying to load data from a specific file type? Could you be a lot more specific?

Comment: What type of file are you loading (like ASCII or MAT) and what is the type of the `u` and `v` fields of the `data` struct (like double vectors or scalars)?

Comment: @TroyHaskin - the files are .mat files, and the u and v fields in the data struct are coming up as "doubles"

Comment: So then, without more information, I will assume that `data.u` and `data.v` are `1 x 26` vectors of doubles.  So simply assign them to `u` and `v` variables (e.g. `u = data.u;`) and reference individual data using vector indexing: `u(1)`, `u(2)`, ...  `u(26)`.  [See here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html) for more details and examples.

Comment: @TroyHaskin sorry for the lack of information! They're 29x39 but I want 26 of each (so 26 29x39 matrices for each of u and v) and right now I'm only seeing one of each. Then later I want to reference a specific position (i, j) in the kth version of each.

Comment: Ah, then one solution may be to make `u` and `v` 3D arrays and loop through assigning data along the third dimension.  For example, `u = zeros(29,39,26);` and then loop making the assignment `u(:,:,k) = data.u` for the `k`-th assignment. Does that help?

Comment: @TroyHaskin I think that does help thank you!!